# Can Statsvn filter out statistics by date

Tags: svn, statsvn

Just wanted to check if there is any configuration or parameter to get statistics in a provided date range rather than it's giving stats from DAY1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since StatSVN is running on locale log files, it's totally possible:

1. Check out a working copy of your project from Subversion.

   `svn co svn://server/repo/trunk/modulename`
2. Create a Subversion log file, specifying the date range you want:

   `svn log -v -r {2012-05-01}:{2012-05-31} --xml > logfile.log`
3. Run StatSVN:

   `java -jar /path/to/statsvn.jar /path/to/module/logfile.log /path/to/module`

   This command creates the HTML reports in the current directory.

More details are available from the [User Manual](http://wiki.statsvn.org/User%20Manual.ashx).

Comment: Thank you, got the same solution from statsvn folks too :)